# If $K \leq G $ and $H\triangleleft G$ then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $K \leq G $ and $H\triangleleft G$ then $HK=\{hk : h \in H, k\in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

My try:

How $e \in H$ and $e \in K$ then $ee=e \in HK$

and let $h_1k_1, h_2k_2 \in HK$ then $h_1k_1h_2k_2=h_1h_3k_1k_2$ because $H$ is normal (that implies that $ha=ah'$ for all $a\in G$)

and how $h_1 $ and $h_3$ are in $H$ then $h_1h_3\in H$ and the same for $k_1$ and $k_2$ so $h_1k_1h_2k_2=h_1h_3k_1k_2 \in HK$

and $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}=h'k^{-1}$ again because $H$ is normal so $(hk)^{-1} \in HK$
so $HK \leq G$ is right?

Comment: Right. -- An alternative approach might use that $HK=\pi^{-1}(\pi(K))$ where $\pi\colon G\to G/H$ is the canonical homomorphism to the quotient

Comment: Do you already know that if $\;H,\,K\;$ are two subgroups of a group  $\;G\;$ , then $\;HK\;$ is also a subgroup of $\;G\;$ iff $\;HK=KH\;$ ? This is the easy way to solve this problem...

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

You have used the [two-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test). It is required that you show that $HK\subseteq G$. This is easy though: since $HK=\{hk\color{red}{\in G}\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$, we have $HK\subseteq G$.